# New Kernel update not showing Wifi

Tags: drivers, kernel

I have Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS desktop with kernel 5.13.0-52-generic and my wifi device DWA 131 with rtl8192eu driver was functioning perfectly after every software update till this kernel version. Today after software update with kernel 5.15.0-41-generic, my wifi is not getting detected. Kindly help and pls let me know the fix, procedure for the same. Thanks and Regards.

I originally installed drivers for DWA 131 (rtl8192eu) with the following link :

https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

Comment: Simply repeat the procedure you did before. You'll have to do it each time there's a kernel update.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, repeating the steps from my above link was not needed for every kernel update. That was the speciality of the mentioned link. Anyway now something got disturbed after kernel update and reinstall is the last resort, anyway thanks for your reply.